# Linking "See also" items in Matlab when publishing using markup

Tags: matlab

I wish to publish documentation using Matlab's publish feature. My documentation is in markup format (i.e. contains sections using "%%"), which seems to have the side effect of removing hyperlinks to 'see also' items.

For example, the following header comment will not hyperlink to the knnsearch doc when published:

```
%% myFunction
% Short description of function.
%
%% Syntax
%  myOutput = myFunction(myInput);
%
%% Description
% Longer description of function.
%
%  myInput  - description of input
%  myOutput - description of output
%
%% Example
%  myOutput = myFunction('blah');
%
%% See also
%  knnsearch
```

How do I retain 'see also' hyperlinks when using Matlab's publish feature with markup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you're asking for; publishing doesn't automatically add a link to See Also lines, in the same way that `doc` or `help` does.

But you can achieve something similar by directly adding a link to your markup:

```
%% See also
% <matlab:doc('knnsearch') knnsearch>
```

If you want your function to have the normal functionality of `doc` or `help`, and also this functionality, consider including both your normal See Also section, plus a `<matlab: >` link in something like a "See" rather than "See Also" section.